# Efficient way to display the List View in Android

Tags: android, listview

I have attached the screen shot of my custom list view. I want to display it efficiently. What is the best possible way to do it?

[image]

thanks
Sneha[image]

i have uploaded another list view screen display . But alignment is not proper in it. How to resolve it??

Comment: what do you mean by efficient? Space wise or memory wise?

Comment: If you want to make your list more efficient space wise,you can use expandable list.Below is the link you can implement ex. list view. http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/09/expandablelistview-on-android.html

Answer (score 2):

With ListView there is a very standard method to improve its performance.

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.text_item, parent, false);
        }

        ((TextView) convertView).setText(getItem(position));

        return convertView;
    }
```

Basically, you dont need to inflate the convertview all time, you can inflate it once and use it the next time on. The above is a very standard practice, read about it on http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=422

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about how to make the look more aesthetically pleasant then I would suggest you to use Table layout inside each row to organize all the information